# Increases localscale depending on mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do something that does not suit me. I want my object to scale depending on the position of the mouse on the y-axis.

```
void Update()
{
    var mPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    mPosition.z = 0;
    target.transform.position = mPosition;
    float scaleValue = Mathf.Round(mPosition.y);
    target.transform.localScale = new Vector3(target.transform.localScale.x + scaleValue / 50f, target.transform.localScale.y + scaleValue / 50f, 0f);
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canShoot)
    {
        Fire();
    }
}
```

The problem is that once the game starts, the object (target) is growing steadily. I just want to do some kind of effect, when I move the mousse up the object shrinks, when it moves down the object grows. What I'm wrong with, thank you!!!

Comment: what do you want the scale to be for y=0? for y=10? for y=100? PartTimeIndie has written a solid answer but you haven't provided the information they would need to give you anything more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding to your local scale on each frame. You should do something along those lines:

```
Vector3 startScale;
void Awake(){
    startScale =   target.transform.localScale;
}
void Update()
{
    var mPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    mPosition.z = 0;
    target.transform.position = mPosition;
    float scaleValue = Mathf.Round(mPosition.y);
    // you probably need to change the scaleValue to make it make more sense
    target.transform.localScale =startScale  * scaleValue;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canShoot)
    {
        Fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that, but it's gotta work on the code, because if y == 0, the scale is 0. I have to do something like: if y == -5 then target.localscale = 1f, if y == -4 then target.localscale = 0.9f....and so on

Comment: yea I figured, it was more to point you to the right direction ;)